# Javascript Sorting Large Table

Tags: javascript

I have 3 large tables, resp1, resp2, and resp3.  Each object in these tables are anonymous tables.

I can combine the tables very easily with `var list = (resp1.concat(resp2)).concat(resp3);`, but I want to sort them in a very specific way, then combine them.

Each anonymous table contains an index called Number, with a number as the value.  I want the anonymous tables with the smallest Numbers to be first in the table, and the second smallest Number to be next, and so on and so forth.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: When you say 'anonymous tables' - what do you mean? 'tables' are not a data structure in JavaScript, you sound like you are describing objects.

Comment: There is no such thing called "table" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I go about doing this?

Put all the objects in your tables in an array. Then sort that array by the `Number` index of its anonymous table. Then join the array into the new table.

If you would give us more details (code) about what "object" or "anonymous table" means, we can further help you with this.